# Infinite Suzuki Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups, infinite-groups

Often I found myself on a symbol like $Sz(F)$ where $F$ is an infinite field.

What is the definition of an **infinite** Suzuki group?

Are they linear groups?

Where I could find some informations about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suzuki groups are subgroups of an algebraic group of type $B_2$.
Reference: Modular Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type.

Comment: Yes, but you are speaking about the finite Suzuki groups, I think.

Comment: You misunderstand. The definition of the Suzuki groups is a definition that works over arbitrary fields (with certain properties) just as algebraic groups can be defined over arbitrary fields (over some base field or ring like the integers). All you need is the algebraic group of type $B_2$ which exists over any field and a certain automorphism (which restricts the possible fields, but still allows infinite examples).

Comment: I think you need the field to be perfect, and for there to exist a field automorphism $\theta$ such that $\theta^2$ is the automorphims $x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Will this restrict the characteristic of the field to $2$?

Comment: @DerekHolt I think it's ok if $\theta$ is an endomorphism s.t. "$\theta^2 = 2$" too. (Sometimes called a Tits endomorphism.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below. You can find some info on wiki.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki_groups

Comment: The only informations I can find on Wikipedia are about the FINITE Suzuki groups.